# YII2 Putting Cycle in partial view and using it in layout – include vs render?

Tags: php, yii2

I would like to use the sjaakp\cycle\Cycle::widget in my main layout in order to have a banner slideshow. 
When putting the code directly into the main layout, it works pretty well. 
But in order to make the layout more readable, I would like to put the code into a separate php file, says _banner-slide-show.php and use

```
<?php $this->render('_banner-slide-show');?>
```

but it doesn't work. The pages are visible but the banner slideshow doesn't appear and there is no trace of images in the source code of pages.

If I use

```
<?php include ('_banner-slide-show.php')
```

It works pretty well again.

My question is why doesn't it work with render ?

here is the code in _banner-slide-show.php

```
                 <?php
             use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;
             use yii\helpers\Url;


                // $photos = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'banner', 1);
                    $photos = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] 
                            . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..'
                            . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..'.
                            '/images/admin/banner', 1);
                    $dataPhotos = array();
                    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
                       // array_push($dataPhotos, ['photo' => '@web/banner/' . $photo]);
                        $url=Url::to(['/image/view', 'filePath' => 'admin/banner/'.$photo]);
array_push($dataPhotos,['photo' => $url]) ;
                    }

                    array_pop($dataPhotos);
                    array_pop($dataPhotos); //remove . and ..


                    $dataProv = new ArrayDataProvider(['allModels' => $dataPhotos,
                        'pagination' => false]);
                    ?>
                    <?=
                    sjaakp\cycle\Cycle::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProv,
                        'imgAttribute' => 'photo',
                        // 'captionAttributes' => ['photo'],
                        // 'overlayAttributes' =>['photo'],
                        'options' => [
                            'captionPlugin' => 'caption2',
                            'captionFxOut' => 'slideUp',
                            'captionFxIn' => 'slideDown',
                            'allow-wrap' => false,
                            'auto-height' => 0,
                            'fx' => 'fadeOut',
                            'timeout' => 8000,
                            'speed' => 2000,
                        //    'overlay' => '#ovl'
                        ],
                    ])
                    ?>
                    <!-- <div id="ovl" class="cycle-overlay"></div> -->
```

Comment: where you have placed  the _banner-slide-show.php?   could be you need  a proper path setting ..

Comment: are you sure that _banner-slide-show.php is in the main folder?

Comment: It is placed in the same folder than the layout main.php

Comment: Placing something like

Comment: echo something; exit(); shows that _banner-slide-show is accessed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print the return statment of `$this->render()` on the page.

`<?php echo $this->render('_banner-slide-show');?>`

or
`<?= $this->render('_banner-slide-show');?>`

Greetings Azoth